# Need to write SQL statement to copy a value from one field to another where a condition is true

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not a SQL expert (by any means). I know I can do this programatically in vb.net (which I will if I can't figure out how to do it with an SQL statement).

I need to copy the value of a field in one table to another field in a separate table where a specific condition is true.  I've tried my best to model it below:

- Table1.field1
- Table1.field2
- Table2.field1
- Table2.field2

I want to copy the value

```
from :Table2.field2 
To   :Table1.field2

where Table1.field1 = Table2.field1 (There are about 3000 rows).
```

Basically I have some string information in one field for a whole bunch of records where I need to copy that to the same records but in a different field in a different table. Does that make sense?

I know I'm supposed to provide some code to show I'm trying; however, I really don't know where to even start. I'm willing to tough it out on my own if maybe someone can point me in the right direction? I'd appreciate any help/guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server, you can [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) a table using a join:

```
UPDATE t1
 SET t1.field2 = t2.field2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  If I want to copy the value from t2.field2 and put it in t1.field2 should I reverse the SET you wrote, or does this already do that?  I'm a beginner with SQL so I may not be reading your statement correctly.  Thank you!

Comment: I think I had it backwards, you are correct.  I've updated the answer!

Comment: This works perfect!  Thank you so much.  SQL has always been my Achilles heel.  Time to hit the books again.